# How to let the constructor in the subclass inherit the constructor or base class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abc

I have the following code segment, which is shown as follows along with its output

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
  
class AbstractClass(object, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        print('the salary information')
 
 
class Employee(AbstractClass):
    def __init__(self, salary, name):
        self.salary = salary
        self.name = name
        super(AbstractClass,self).__init__()
 
emp1 = Employee(1000000, "Tom")
print(emp1.salary)
print(emp1.name)
```

I would like to let the subclass, e.g. `Employee`, can also inherit the functionality implemented in the constructor of `AbstractClass`. In specific, the `print('the salary information')` I added:

```
super(AbstractClass,self).__init__()  # which does not work
```

Comment: Worth noting, by the way, that changing the signature of `__init__` in a subclass like this violates the Liskov Substitution Principle, so may not be advisable. Difficult to advise on a fix as it's not clear what the purpose of your `n` attribute is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the CURRENT class to `super`, not the parent.  So:

```py
        super(Employee,self).__init__()
```

Python will figure out which parent class to call.

When you do that, it won't work, because `AbstractClass.__init__` requires an additional parameter that you aren't providing.

**FOLLOWUP**

It has been correctly pointed out that this will suffice:

```py
        super().__init__(0)
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use the zero argument form here?  `super().__init__('n')`? (or whatever `n` is in the super init)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  He needs to provide some argument to `super().__init__`.  We don't know what the argument needs to be.  I suspect this is all just a skeleton for the sake of the question anyway.

Comment: I'm asking if you really *need* to pass the CURRENT class to super. Why not just `super()` instead of `super(Employee,self)`.

Comment: Yes, you can.  That was a change in Python 3.0 (before that, you DID have to specify the base class), and I use `super` so rarely I forget.  Good point.